# ASP.Net Page layout is not displaying properly in QA machine but is displaying correctly in Dev Machine

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net Page layout is not displaying properly in QA machine but is displaying correctly in Dev Machine.  What could be the issue? We are using ASP.Net 2.0

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying properly"?

Answer (score 0):

Very common issues are:

- QA machine still has old resources in the browser cache

  IE: Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Refresh
   FF, Chrome: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Refresh
- Resource Paths are different.

  Somewhere a path to an image starts with "/" which relates to to absolute route of a page.
  On the dev machine the page is: `localhost:8080/default.aspx`
  On the QA its: `localhost:8080/somepath/default.aspx`

  This will not work anymore, replace the absolute paths or make sure the path depth is the same everywhere